# Delay loop calculation in assembly code

Tags: assembly, nios

Lets say I want the inner loop to be 1ms long and want to calculate the delaycount parameter. We know that F = 50 Mhz.

We can clearly see that there are 3 instructions in the inner loop. Lets also assume that the instructions take 1 cycle each. Thus the result  is:

```
        .equ    delaycount,     0 #set right delay value here!
        .text                   # 
        .global delay           # 

delay11:  beq     r4,r0,fin       # exit outer loop

        movi    r8,delaycount   # delay estimation for 1ms

in:  beq     r8,r0,out     # exit from inner loop

        subi    r8,r8,1         # decrement inner counter

        br      in

out:  subi    r4,r4,1         # decrement outer counter
        br      delay11


fin:    ret
```

Solution :

**F = 50 Mhz T = 20 ns**

**1ms = 20ns * 3 *  delaycount**

**Delaycount = 1ms/3*20ns = 16666**

However the solution provides that delaycount is equal to **12000**. Could anybody show that this is correct?

Comment: Should we assume your registers are 8 bit or 16 bit or 32 bit? It matters, as your 3 instructions you assume are not entirely true. You forgot to count in the 4 instructions in the outer loop, running whenever inner loop is done.

Comment: Also, if the CPU has some instruction pipeline and needs to reload it after a jump, you will not be able to maintain the 1 cycle per instruction assumption. Not to mention interrupts and other stuff which could have an impact.

Comment: Its a 32 bit processor nios II

Comment: Last question: What is the value of r0? It only appears in comparisons but is never initialized.

Comment: The _Nios II Core Implementation Details_ says that a _correctly predicted taken branch_ (it's unclear if that includes unconditional branches) takes 2 cycles.

Comment: It also says that it has a 6 stage (instruction?) pipeline. With the branch prediction... hm...

Comment: Yeah.. So we cant assume that all of the instructions are 1 cycle each right?

Comment: Yes - and assuming they WOULD hold, you don't need 2 loops to reach 1ms (at the 20ns cycle time) if you have 32 bit registers. R4 is also an unknown. Often, beq etc. instructions have different cycle times for the branch and no-branch cases.

Comment: https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii51015.pdf Table 9 explains cycle times and instructions etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using information from [the data sheet](https://www.altera.com/content/dam/altera-www/global/en_US/pdfs/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii51015.pdf), especially table 9:

> Branch (correctly predicted, taken) 2
>
> Branch (correctly predicted, not taken) 1

and the logic of the code, I conclude that while the inner loop is running it is a 4 cycle loop, not a 3 cycle loop.

The 12000 value for the delaycount variable then yields: 12000 * 4 * 20ns = 960000ns ~ 1ms.

And thus I would confirm that 12000 is correct, give or take.

Since it is an FPGA design, testing should be easy by toggling a port pin in a test program using the delay and connecting an oscilloscope/logic analyzer to the pin.